# Confusing Syntax of Spreading React Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const RoundedIcon = ({
  name,
  size,
  color,
  backgroundColor,
}: RoundedIconProps) => {
  return (
    <Box
      height={size}
      width={size}
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
      style={{ borderRadius: size / 2 }}
      {...{ backgroundColor }}
    />
  );
};
```

I understand how to use the spread operator and how you can easily spread the rest of any additional props to a React child, but can someone explain to me why this person is adding extra curly braces to an already destructered prop 'backgroundColor' of RoundedIcon component?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Someone didn't like to write `backgroundColor={backgroundColor}` so he wrote `{...{backgroundColor}}`. Yes, it's confusing code. No shame being confused by it.

Comment: @Martin Could you explain the mechanics of it, because the syntax is confusing. I'm reading it as destructuring + rest operator usage? I'm not even sure

Comment: @JohnP First look at the inner set of curly braces: that is a short-hand notation to create a new object with a property named `backgroundColor` and that property has the value that is currently stored behind backgroundColor. The outer set of curly braces with the spread operator is a special JSX feature to take all properties from the spread object and apply them to the element. But there is only the one property `backgroundColor`. So the whole spiel is equivalent to `backgroundColor={backgroundColor}`

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it does not make sense. It may just be an artefact of this person doing:

```
{...{ backgroundColor, name, color }}
```

and then not needing name or color anymore to be spreaded in the props. So leaving

```
{...{ backgroundColor }}
```

Because it's exactly the same as:

```
backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
```

---

After writing this, I realized that it may be faster to type, and so you don't have a messy two times 'backgroundColor' in your code.

Comment: According to this link right at the bottom: https://riptutorial.com/reactjs/example/13689/passing-down-props-using-spread-operator
It's supposedly destructuring the props you want selectively, but what would be the point of this? I'm still not understanding the syntax behind this.

Answer (score 1):

In your case above spreading `{...{ backgroundColor }}` will pass `backgroundColor` in props to the child component. But if you want to rename the variable you have to spread it like below:

```
function ComponentA() {
  const backgroundColor = "red";

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Component A</p>
      <ComponentB {...{ helloWorld: backgroundColor }} />
    </div>
  );
}

function ComponentB(props) {
  console.log(props); // { helloWorld: "red" }

  return <div>Component B</div>;
}
```

Comment: Explain like I'm 5, why writing backgroundColor={backgroundColor} is possibly not efficient as the approach above? And what does it mean to do the spread operator, followed by another set of curly braces when forwarding props?

Is it to create a separate copy of the props I'm forwarding (to make original forwarded props immutable by child component?)  and then specifying which props I explicitly want forwarded?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is any reason why this `{...{ backgroundColor }}` is better than  `backgroundColor={backgroundColor}`

Comment: I actually seems like a pretty common pattern when controlling props to children components; but just trying to understand meaning of it and how it works